# Валидация при аякс запросе

Tags: ajax, валидация, форма

Уважаемые, прошу помощи.
Я пока мало что понимаю в програмировании, от того пожалуй и вопросы которые кажутся скорее всего глупыми
Мне нужно отправить данные с формы аякс запросом, но я не могу понять как добавить сюда минимальную валидацию, что бы юзер не мог отправить пустые значения

Вот форма

```
<form class="validate"  id="firstForm" method="POST">

                <div>
                    <label for="Firstname">Firstname:</label>
                    <input onkeyup="checkParams()" id="Firstname" type="text" class="classFirstname" name="Firstname" placeholder="Firstname" >
                    
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Lastname">Lastname:</label>
                    <input onkeyup="checkParams()" id="Lastname" type="text" required="ererer" class="classLastname" name="Lastname" placeholder="Lastname" >
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Birthdate">Birthdate:</label>
                    <input onkeyup="checkParams()" type="date" class="classBirthdate" name="Birthdate" placeholder="Birthdate" >
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Report">Report Subject:</label>
                    <input onkeyup="checkParams()" type="text" required="erererererer" class="classReport" name="Report" placeholder="Report subject">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Country">Country:</label>
                    <select onkeyup="checkParams()" class="classCountry"name="Country" placeholder="Country" >
                       
                </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Phone">Phone:</label>
                    <input onkeyup="checkParams()" type="tel" class="classPhone" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone">  
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <input onkeyup="checkParams()" type="Email" class="classEmail" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
                    
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit" class="classfirstSubmit" id="firstFormSubmit">Next</button> 

            </form>
```

Пытался сделать вот так, но бесполезно

```
function checkParams() {
            var valFistame = $('#Firstname').val();
            var valLastname = $('#Lastname').val();
            var valBirthdate = $('#Birthdate').val();
             
            if(name.length != 0 && email.length != 0 && phone.length != 0) {
                $('#firstFormSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#firstFormSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
```

```
$('button.classfirstSubmit').on('click', function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('button.classfirstSubmit').on('click', function(){
                         
                            var ValueFirstname = $('input.classFirstname').val();
                            var ValueLastname = $('input.classLastname').val();
                            var ValueBirthdate = $('input.classBirthdate').val();
                            var ValueReport = $('input.classReport').val();
                            var ValueCountry = $('select.classCountry').val();
                            var ValuePhone = $('input.classPhone').val();
                            var ValueEmail = $('input.classEmail').val();



                            $.ajax({
                                method: "POST",
                                url: "some.php",
                                data: { Firstname: ValueFirstname, Lastname: ValueLastname, Birthdate: ValueBirthdate, Report: ValueReport, Country: ValueCountry, Phone: ValuePhone, Email: ValueEmail }
                            })
                                .done(function(){
                                    //alert('Data Saved:' + msg);
                                })
                                                 $('input.classFirstname').val('');
                                                 $('input.classLastname').val('');
                                                 $('input.classBirthdate').val('');
                                                 $('input.classReport').val('');
                                                 $('input.classCountry').val('');
                                                 $('input.classPhone').val('');
                                                 $('input.classEmail').val('');
                        })
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" disabled ... 

function checkParams() {
  var valFistame = $('#Firstname').val();
  var valLastname = $('#Lastname').val();
  var valBirthdate = $('#Birthdate').val();
         
  if (valFistame.length && valLastname.length && valBirthdatelength) {
    ...
```